# Где посмотреть цвет кнопки по умолчанию?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть стандартная кнопка:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

При удержании кнопки, она программно меняет цвет. При отжатии должна возвращаться к первоначальному цвету:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
    button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("Как определить первоначальный цвет?"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Где посмотреть цвет кнопки по умолчанию?

Comment: @RealKEK, подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: см. ответ._____

Comment: Вообще для таких вещей есть [`StateList` (xml тег `<selector>`)](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/drawable.php#state-list), который позволяет минимумом кода (созданием одного xml-файла)  указать действия для нажатий, выделения и прочих экшенов на виджетах, зачем писать свой костыль.

Answer (score 1):

Берёте с кнопки бэкграунд, приводите в `ColorDrawable`, и сохраняете этот цвет в поле.

Если коротко, вот:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
int colorId = colorDrawable.getColor();
```

А такой у вас должен получиться код:

```
int colorId;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
        colorId = colorDrawable.getColor();

        button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                colorId, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

И еще настоятельно вам советую не ставить громоздкие `findViewById()` в такие методы как `onTouch()` - может тормозить.

Comment: А для чего служит в данном примере строка  `Drawable buttonBackground = button1.getBackground();`

Comment: Наверное задумка была вынести `Drawable buttonBackground = button1.getBackground();` перед `if`. И в дальнейшем использовать `buttonBackground` вместо `button1.getBackground()`?

Comment: Это хороший ответ, но есть ошибки в коде который Вы опубликовали.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Не представляю, как я мог такой бред написать

Comment: Бывает с каждым без исключения )) Вот теперь Ваш ответ могу отметить как полезный. Ведь Хороший ответ кому-то поможет сохранить пару часов а может и дней!

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить цвет фона кнопки в `Hex` формате так:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
ColorDrawable btnBackgroundColor = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();
//далее приводим цвет к `Hex` формату
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & btnBackgroundColor.getColor());
```

Если делать изменение цвета Вашим способом используя `MotionEvent`то код будет для даного примера таким:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button1.getBackground();
    String firstColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & buttonColor.getColor());

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(firstColor), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте следующее:

```
button1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

Comment: btn_default отличается от первоначальной кнопки. btn_default с темной рамкой, а кнопка по умолчанию без нее. Картинка для иллюстрации: https://ru.files.fm/u/hxh9exwa

Answer (score 0):

Цвет по умолчанию будет таким, каким назначите в xml-файле. Например:

```
android:background="#4ade3d"
```

Comment: а каким будет цвет, если background не назначать?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто:
создал свою кнопку xml в drawable, задал ее первоначальный цвет и использовал его в дальнейшем.